# Visual Studio 2008 report designer multiple values passed for single label parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2008, report-designer

In parameter properties is there a way to pass multiple values with one label?  I have a drop down box containing 7 choices on which department is desired some departments only have one account code and others multiple.  I've tried ('123', '321') this would be equivelent to the query syntax needed.  The code I'm using now for the parameter in syntax is (table.column IN (@parameter)) should this be written differently?

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
    FROM gl_master,   
     gl_master_comp_v,   
     budget_off_mstr  
    WHERE ( gl_master.acct_cde = gl_master_comp_v.acct_cde ) and  
     ( gl_master.budget_officer = budget_off_mstr.budget_officer ) and  
     ( ( gl_master_comp_v.acct_comp1 = '01' ) AND  
     ( budget_off_mstr.budget_officer in (@BudgetOfficer) ) )
```

Comment: Could you provide a code sample of how this is accessed so we can understand a bit more clearly?

Comment: Alright, so I made a new dataset created a query calling the numbers I wanted.  Created a parameter using that query and called on the parameter from another parameter...no dice...I feel like I'm almost there just need a push

Comment: I have tried some info I found talking about splits and filters with no luck.  Maybe, this is just what I need can anyone elaborate on it?

Comment: This link is my exact problem, but I'm not understanding the solution since its still not working. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ef341204-0591-4383-b407-dffd8996405e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.  However, I'm sure there is a simpler/cleaner way of doing this.

I placed the parameter values as the account names.  The account codes were defined within the query and the parameter value was included with a AND.  Basically recreating all of the WHERE for each account name seperated with a OR.  Code below:

```
 WHERE ( g.acct_cde = l.acct_cde ) and  
     ( g.budget_officer = b.budget_officer ) and  
     ( ( l.acct_comp1 = '01' ) ) AND  
     ( b.budget_officer IN ('48564') ) AND 
 (@BudgetOfficer = 'AM') 
OR   
     ( g.acct_cde = l.acct_cde ) and  
     ( g.budget_officer = b.budget_officer ) and  
     ( ( l.acct_comp1 = '01' ) ) AND  
     ( b.budget_officer IN     
('3543', '3523', '06588', '58568', '48656','58544', '48648') ) AND 
(@BudgetOfficer = 'Dean_AA')
      OR
```

and so on...